# QGIS Rasterize PolygonZM

Tags: qgis, centroids

I have a triangulated DEM PolygonZM shape and would like to Rasterize it in QGIS (3.2).
[image]

I couldn´t find an option to use the geometry´s z value so i tried to create a field and calculate the centroid´s Z values.

But i´m kind of stumped as to how to do it.

Using "centroid($geometry) removes the z-values so it seems i can´t use the z() function.
[image]

If i use "vector -> geometry tools -> centroids", the resulting geometry is 2d as well.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract points from the TIN using Vector->Geometry tools->Extract vertices. I tried it on a PolylineZ layer and Z values were preserved.

I suppose you had better to use the TIN interpolation to rasterize the original triangles, you can find it in the processing toolbox: QGIS->Interpoation->TIN (or you can select other interpolation method. If you would like to preserve TIN edges as break lines in your model than add 3D polygons as break lines.

[image: Original triangles]

Original layer 3D data

[image: interpolation parameters and result]

interpolation parameters and result

Comment: TIN interpolation works for a small subset of the data, but once i try the whole dataset (~290k features), it stops with an unknown Exception.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference - a possible workflow in QGIS >= 3.6:

- Run the "Extract Z Values" algorithm on your PolygonZM input, and either extract the first vertex's Z value to an attribute (the default behaviour), or extract a derived statistic based on the Z values to an attribute (e.g. the mean/median/min/max z value -- the algorithm has options for all of these)
- Run the Rasterize (vector to raster) algorithm on the output from Extract Z Values. Select your newly created Z value field as the "field to use for a burn-in value". Clear the "fixed value to burn" field. Fill in the resolution/extent parameters as desired, and run.

The output will be a raster containing the z values from the original PolygonZM input vector.